# Which IP is being used in @file psexec

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I am running a command of PSEXEC, which is reading IPs from a text file using

```
Psexec @IPlist.txt -u adc -p P@$rCL cmd /c WHERE /r D:\ %n%>res.txt
```

how can I know that which IP is currently being used from @IPlist.txt, can I store it in variable or can I pass it to another batch file?

Comment: It's where.exe, an external command, so you don't need `cmd /c` for the single command. You'd need it for a more complex command line such as `cmd /c "(netsh interface ip show address "Ethernet" | findstr "IP Address") & (where /r D:\ %n%)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the list in the text file "manually" with a batch file, calling psexec multiple times, or instead of that "WHERE" command you could write a batch file that is called by psexec that then determines the IP address of the PC it is currently running on (whilst then running on the client PC, using eg. netsh).

Comment: that is a workable solution, however this would be too many scripts, I was looking for some switch or by default variable if any offered by batch scripting to extract the current value of @file being used.